# Bootstrap website not mobile responsive due to content overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment, bootstrap-5

I'm new to web development. Currently, I'm building a bootstrap website. My website works fine one the desktop mod. But in the mobile view, some bootstrap columns are overflow and creates a vertical white space in the mobile screen. So inspect chrome developer tools I found if I was able to  untick

```css
.row {
  margin-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)/ -2);
  margin-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)/ -2);
}
```

I'm able to solve my problem. So I set my CSS file row value :

```css
.row { 
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
}
```

But this code doesn't execute on the browser.

This is the my problem img

[image]

This is the chrome inspect tool solution

[image]

This code work fine on the codeply online editor mobile version. But not in the real mobiles and chrome developer tools.

This is my project

https://www.codeply.com/p/mTCzjeZu7T

Comment: you forgot `container` or `contain-fluid` class

Comment: like this way https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#example

Comment: Thanks, I put that in the div but it's not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-structured your html code with proper grid structure. The root cause of the extra space could be unstructured row class in between div. Also has to remove #title class padding to remove extra spaces. Please refer the snippet.

```css
body{ 
    
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;}



.h1{
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive; ;
  }
h1{
      font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
  }
  
h2{
      font-family: 'DM Serif Text', serif;
  }
  

/*.row{*/
/* margin-left: 0%;*/
/* margin-right: 0%;*/
/*}*/

#title{
 background-color:#F8F5F1;
 /* padding: 1% 1%; */

}

.title-image{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;

}

.name{
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 30%;
}

/* menu bar */
.lg-bar{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 1% 5%;
}

.n2{
    padding: 0 18px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* .dn1{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 1% 3%;
} */
.nv{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 3% 4%;
}
.dnb{
  padding: 4% 4%;
}

.b1{
 font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive; 
 

}

.dni{
    color: white;
    font-family:'Black Ops One', cursive;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 1%;
    margin-top: 3%;

}

.pn{
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
}


/* new release */
.new1{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    font-size: 4rem ;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    
}

.new{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    font-size: 4rem ;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}




.new-col1{
   padding: 1%
}

.new-img{
    height:auto;
    width: 100%;
}



.new-col2{
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: #B0C4DE;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#3D7EAA,#FFE47A);
}

.new-date{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
    padding-top: 6%;
    
}

.new-tag{
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 7rem;
    font-weight:500;
    padding-left: 5%;
}
.new-tag-sp{
    font-size: 6.5rem;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight:500;
    padding-left: 5%;
}
.new-music1{
   margin: 3% 1% 3% 6%;
}

.new-p{
    padding-left : 6%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
}


.ab{
    background-color: teal;
}

.ab-im-b {
    background-color:#F8F5F1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#F8F5F1,#bfe9ff);
}

.ab-im{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
    margin-right: 0%;
}


.ab-tx1{
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 padding: 3% 1%;
}
.ab-tx1:hover{
background-color: #6dd5ed;
}

.ab-tx2{
 background-color: #808080;
 padding: 3% 1%;
}
.ab-tx2:hover{
    background-color: #264566;
}

.ab-tx3{
 background-color:  #D3D3D3;
 padding: 3% 1%;
}
.ab-tx3:hover{
    background-color: #D7C2AD;
}
.ab-tx4{
 background-color:  #808080;
 padding: 3% 1%;
}
.ab-tx4:hover{
    background-color: #753a88;
}
.ab-bu{
    outline-color: black;
    background-color: cornsilk;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 6% ;
    margin-right: 6%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    
}

.ab-tx{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
 font-size: 7rem;
 margin-top: 20%;
 margin-left: 6%;
 margin-right: 6%;

}
.ab-tx-sp{
    color: white;
 font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
 font-size: 7rem;
 margin-top: 20%;
 margin-left: 6%;
 margin-right: 6%;
}


.ab-p{
color: white;
font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.8rem;
margin-left: 6%;
margin-right: 6%;
}



/* .brand */
#brand{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 3% 2%;
}

.girl2{
    width: 100% ;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}


.news{
    padding-bottom:0%;
}
.brand-img{
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
    
}

.thoughts{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3% 10%;
}
.t-h2{
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.t-h4{
    font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.t-h42{
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* follow */
#follow{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5% 3%;
    text-align: center;
    

}

.icon{
   
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  
}
.icon:hover{
    color:white
}

/* footer */


#footer{
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    
}
    
@media (min-width:150px) and (max-width:298px){
    body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;}

    .name{
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }
    
    .new1{
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .new-img{
        padding: 0% 3% 3% 3%;
    }

    .new-date{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .new-tag{
        font-size: 3rem;

    }

    .new-tag-sp{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .new{
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .ab-tx{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .ab-tx-sp{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .ab-p{
        font-size: 2rems;
    }

    .t-h2{
        font-size: 3rem;
        padding: 3% 0%;
    }

    .t-h4{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    
}

@media (min-width:300px) and (max-width:600px) {

    body{ 
    
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;}
    


    .title-image{
     padding-top: 30%;
    }

    .name{
        padding-top: 1%;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 0%;
        padding-right: 0%;
        margin: 0%;
    }

    .new1{
        font-size: 4rem;
        padding:3% 2%;
    }
    
    .new-img{
        padding-bottom: 5%;
        padding-right: 2%;
        padding-left: 2%;
        margin: 0%;
    }


    .new-tag{
        font-size: 5rem;
        
    }
    .new-tag-sp{
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    
    .new-row{
       padding-bottom: 0%;
       margin-bottom: 0%;
    }

    .new-img{
        padding-right: 1%;
        padding-left: 0%;
     }

    #albums{
        padding-bottom: 0%;
    }

    .ab-tx{
        font-size: 5rem;
    }

    .ab-tx-sp{
        font-size: 3.8rem;
    }

    .ab-p{
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    .ab-bu{
        padding-top: 2%;
        margin-bottom: 15%;
    }



    .t-h2{
        font-size: 3rem;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3% 0%;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .t-h4{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 1%;
        
    }

    .thoughts{
        padding: 12% 0%;
    }

   

    #follow{
        padding-top: 10%;
    }
}

@media (min-width:600px) and (max-width:900px){
    body{ 
    
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;}
    


    .name{
       text-align: center;
       margin-top: 0%;
       padding-top: 0%;
       padding-bottom: 5%;
    }

    .new-img{
       padding-right: 1%;
       padding-left: 0%;
       padding-bottom: 3%;
    }

    .ab-tx1 {
        padding-bottom: 12%;
    }

    .ab-tx2 {
        padding-bottom: 12%;
    }

    .ab-tx3 {
        padding-bottom: 12%;
    }

    .ab-tx4 {
        padding-bottom: 12%;
    }

    .thoughts{
        padding: 20% 0%;
    }

    .t-h2{
        padding-bottom: 3%;
    }

    .t-h42{
        padding-top: 3%;
    }

    #follow{
        padding-top: 6%;
    }
 
}




@media (min-width:995px) and (max-width:1500px){
 .name{
    font-size: 3.4rem;
    text-align: center;
 }

 .thoughts{
    padding: 20% 0%;
}

.t-h42{
    padding-top: 3%;
}

.ab-tx-sp{
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.news{
padding-bottom: 0%;
}

.brand-img{
    padding-top: 3%;
}

#follow{
    padding-top: 12%;
}

}




@media (min-width:900px) {

    body{ 
    
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    

    #toTopBtn {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 26px;
        right: 39px;
        z-index: 98;
        padding: 21px;
        background-color:gray;
        border-radius: 8px;
       
    }
    
    .js .cd-top--fade-out {
        opacity: .5
    }
    
    .js .cd-top--is-visible {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1
    }
    
    .js .cd-top {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s, background-color .3s
    }
    
    .cd-top {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        bottom: var(--cd-back-to-top-margin);
        right: 20px;
        right: var(--cd-back-to-top-margin);
        display: inline-block;
        height: 40px;
        height: var(--cd-back-to-top-size);
        width: 40px;
        width: var(--cd-back-to-top-size);
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) !important;
        background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1571057658/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
        background-color: hsla(5, 76%, 62%, .8);
        background-color: hsla(var(--cd-color-3-h), var(--cd-color-3-s), var(--cd-color-3-l), 0.8)
    }
    
    .height {
        height: 3000px
    }


   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon-96x96.png">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Black+Ops+One&family=DM+Serif+Text&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3d7b617097.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>The Muscian</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="#" id="toTopBtn" class="cd-top text-replace js-cd-top cd-top--is-visible cd-top--fade-out"
        data-abc="true"></a>

        <!-- <div class="d-lg-none d-xl-block d-xl-none dn1">
        
        </div> -->


        <section id="title">


            <!-- title -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img class="title-image" src="images/titleimage.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <!-- <h1 class="name">Sadeesha Prabhashana Music</h1> -->

                </div>
            </div>


        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- lg menu bar -->
        <div class="lg-bar  d-none d-lg-block   ">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark menu-bark pn">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto" style="font-size: 20px">
                        <li class="nav-item item n2">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#new-release">New Release</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item item n2">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#albums">Albums</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item item n2">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#brand">Studio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item item n2">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#follow">Follow</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="new-release">
        <!-- new release -->
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="new1">New Release</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 new-col1">
            <img class="new-img" src="images/new.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 new-col2">
            <h4 class="new-date">release on 20/06/2021</h4>
            <h2 class="new-tag">Now</h2>
            <h2 class="new-tag-sp">Available</h2>
            <h2 class="new-tag">On</h2>
            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/2eIM3hAd3p96AxJclhJM9Y" target="_blank">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg new-music1"><i class="fab fa-spotify"></i>
                    Spotify
                </button>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.deezer.com/en/album/186867412" target="_blank">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg new-music2"> <i class="fab fa-deezer"></i>
                    Deezer
                </button>
            </a>


            <p class="new-p">#Alone Chill Play Now</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="albums">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="new">Albums</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 ab-im-b ">
            <img class="ab-im" src="images/4.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 ab-tx1">
            <h3 class="ab-tx">Sences</h3>
            <p class="ab-p">Pity those who don't feel anything at all.</p>
            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/1S3BnsQgmeWUBugQAvTZw1" target="_blank">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg ab-bu"><i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i> Play
                    Now
                </button>
            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 ab-tx2">
            <h3 class="ab-tx">Alone Chill</h3>
            <p class="ab-p">Chill out, relax and have an open mind.</p>
            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/2eIM3hAd3p96AxJclhJM9Y" target="_blank">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg ab-bu"><i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i> Play
                    Now
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 ab-im-b  ">
            <img class="ab-im" src="images/3.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 ab-im-b  ">
            <img class="ab-im" src="images/2.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 ab-tx3">
            <h3 class="ab-tx-sp">December</h3>
            <p class="ab-p">To appreciate the beauty of a snowflake it is necessary to stand out in the cold.</p>
            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/6OTh7heKygbXOWavxM2xvM" target="_blank">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg ab-bu"><i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i> Play
                    Now
                </button>
            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 ab-tx4 ">
            <h3 class="ab-tx">Secret Noiser</h3>
            <p class="ab-p">True merit, like a river, the deeper it is, the less noise it makes.</p>
            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/45YkxGBsrV9HP7fimQh4pm" target="_blank">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg ab-bu"><i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i> Play
                    Now
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6  ab-im-b ">
            <img class="ab-im" src="images/1.png" alt="">
        </div>
           
            <!-- <h3>Lonely</h3>
            <img src="images/4.png" alt="">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ullamcorper nisl vitae laoreet viverra.
                Proin vestibulum lacinia diam at gravida.
            </p>
            <h4>on air</h4>
    
            <h3>Alone Chill</h3>
            <img src="images/3.png" alt="">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ullamcorper nisl vitae laoreet viverra.
                Proin vestibulum lacinia diam at gravida.
            </p>
            <h4>on air</h4>
    
            <h3>December</h3>
            <img src="images/2.png" alt="">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ullamcorper nisl vitae laoreet viverra.
                Proin vestibulum lacinia diam at gravida.
            </p>
            <h4>on air</h4>
    
            <h3>December</h3>
            <img src="images/1.png" alt="">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ullamcorper nisl vitae laoreet viverra.
                Proin vestibulum lacinia diam at gravida.
            </p>
            <h4>on air</h4> -->
    
            <!-- </section>
    
        listen on
        <section id="listen">
            <h1>Streaming On</h1>
    
            <img src="" alt="">
            <button type="button">Spotify</button>
    
            <img src="" alt="">
            <button type="button">Deezer</button>
    
            <img src="" alt="">
            <button type="button">Youtube</button>
    -->
        
        <!-- brand -->
        
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="brand">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1 class="new">Studio</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 girl">
            <img  class="girl2" src="images/brand-cp-isuru-akalanka.png" alt="">
          
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-7 ">
            <img class="brand-img" src="images/P.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row thoughts">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2 class="t-h2">Thoughts</h2>
            <h4 class="t-h4">
                "Music is the great uniter. An incredible force.
                Something that people who differ on everything and anything else can have in common."
            </h4>
            <h4 class="t-h42">..Sarah Dessen</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="follow">
        <!-- contact me -->

        <div class="col-12 f-r" >
           
                <a class="icon col-lg-3 col-md-6" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                    <div><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-5x"></i></div>
                </a>
                <a class="icon col-lg-3 col-md-6" href="http://wwww.twitter.com" target="_blank">
                    <div><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-5x"></i></div>
                </a>
                <a class="icon col-lg-3 col-md-6" href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
                    <div><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-5x"></i></div>
                </a>
                <a class="icon col-lg-3 col-md-6" href="http://www.youtube.con" target="_blank">
                    <div><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-5x"></i></div>
                </a>
                <!-- <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 icon"></div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" id="footer">
        <!-- footer -->
            <p>© Copyright 2021</p>
            <p>created by Isuru Akalanka</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
    

    





    



      

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="index.js"></script>



 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the row class, make sure to also include the m-0 class alongside it. Doing so should help resolve your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by adding the `gs-0` class tag to my bootstrap column padding. This removed the default padding from my website to align the containers without an overflow.

While I'm trying to find an answer to this problem, I found most of the time this vertical scrollbar shown in the browser because of the div overflow. This happens very often when using images. If your image overflow you can simply add image class
to below code.

```
img{
      width:100%;
      height:auto;  
     }
```

Also, you can try `overflow-x: hidden;`  This is also removed vertical scrollbar from the website. But in my case, this wasn't enough because on the mobile view some of my bootstrap column got overflowed. So I had to remove their default paddings. Also, make sure to add viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Another thing is to wrap your divs with `.container .container-fluid`. But this .container-fluid also has a default padding. If you want to remove this padding you can simply add `p-0`. This is what I learned from this.